# Is it safe to call json_decode on user input?

Tags: php, json

I'm storing a JSON encoded array of integer indexes => integer values in a cookie.

Obviously cookies can be easily manipulated like any other user input, so here's my cookie getter validation:

```
if ($_COOKIE['myCookie']) { //if cookie exists
    $myCookie = json_decode($_COOKIE['myCookie'], true);
    if (!is_array($myCookie)) { //in case decoding fails or bad cookie
        $myCookie = array(); //sets it as empty array
    }
} else { //if cookie doesn't exist, uses an empty array instead
    $myCookie = array();
}
```

Then before using any of the values, I check if it exists in the array and test against a list of white-listed values - this part seems pretty safe but I'm posting it as it's part of the validation:

```
if (!empty($myCookie[$index])) { //checks if index exists and is truthy
    if ($myCookie[$index] !== 1 && $myCookie[$index] !== 2) { //values whitelist
        die('Hacking attempt through cookies exploit.');
    }
    //use the cookie data now
}
```

Back to the question, **is it safe  to call `json_decode` directly on the cookie?** Can users manipulate the cookie to run arbitrary code?

I've been reading around many topics on SO so far and what I found is that `unserialize()` is dimmed unsafe because it calls constructors, but `json_decode` is technically safe. I've read through their php.net pages but those do not address security directly.

My addon is reaching the live beta very soon, so I'm wondering if calling `json_decode` directly on the cookie is safe enough or if I should run some type of validation before calling `json_decode`. I could run a `preg_match` too, but as I'm testing against a whitelist of values before using them, there should be no problem unless `json_decode` somehow runs arbitrary code, which it doesn't, right?

I know that `json_encode` returns `NULL` if it's not valid JSON, but I'm wondering if this is the right approach or **should I add some kind of validation before calling `json_decode`?**

Comment: Who ever can exploit that, can probably hack your code in other bizzare ways u, me and the rest of the world never thought of

Comment: @ItayMoav Thanks for the incentive. `=]` I've just never used `json_decode` on user input before, and apparently there's no way to validate that kind of data besides `json_decode` itself which returns `NULL` if it fails, I think.

Comment: If you are concerned about the integrity of data inside cookies you should sign it using a HMAC and verify the HMAC before you use it. Use a library for that or let a framework do it, it's insanely hard to get it right by yourself!!!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Using `json_decode` to decode the user input directly has no security problem.

It is just string parsing, won't do any string eval.

`json_decode` in php is like `JSON.parse` in javascript, and both of them could be used directly on the user input, they are safe at the decoding time.

But after being decoded, you have to validate the data for your requirement.

Comment: So it's basically just string parsing, no hidden witchery behind it? Thanks for the info. `=]` Guess I was being a little too paranoid.

Comment: To provide some more insight on how this could be misused, see this exploit in Magento: http://karmainsecurity.com/KIS-2016-02 This is the kind of stuff you need to look up for when decoding JSON and running the results through your code.

Answer (score 9):

Insomuch as `json_decode` is correctly implemented, it should be safe to just use without extra pre-processing (in fact, that might be worse, given that you might have bugs in your pre-processor).

Comment: Could you define "correctly implemented"? I assume the PHP 5.4+'s native `json_decode` is correctly implemented. About pre-processing, I wouldn't do any besides running a `preg_match` to check for suspicious data, but the `json_decode` itself will return `NULL` when decoding it fails and as I'm checking the values against a whitelist, there should be no need for it right?

Comment: "correctly implemented" in that, it has not bugs that could allow an attacker inject an exploit. Yes, it should return NULL - more importantly - it shouldn't do anything dangerous while deserializing.

Comment: By the way, just realized my typo. *With* should have been *without*. Ie, *don't* do anything before passing to `json_decode`.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was typo. +1'd since back then, wish I could have more than one accepted answer. Accepted xdazz's answer as he expands a little on how it works and to the point of why pre-processing isn't necessary.

Answer (score 5):

json_decode will fail if the data is not in json format and otherwise will return an nice array for you to work with. Like Itay said if somebody can exploit this he almost deserves to get in. json_decode doesnt suffer from the risk of sql so I'd say you're fine doing this.

Just make sure you clean anything (or white list, like you already are) before incorporating it in a query.

Comment: Didn't add much to what I already knew, but it's always good to hear what I'm thinking in another voice. `=]`